# Metro App How to disable Gridview scrolling

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to disable scrolling in GridView ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this inside of the GridView

```
<GridView
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am wondering whether there will be anyway to disable scrolling in GridView not ListView.

Comment: I think gridview inherits from list view base, so it should work?

Comment: I don't think it does and in any case - it does not matter. You should use the attributes and ignore that it says ListView there. FTFY.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use

```xml
<GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" />
```

If you're setting this property dynamically, the Scrolling will be disabled but the ScrollPosition stays (on *ScrollBarVisibilty=Disabled the ScrollPosition gets set to 0)

Dynamic Example:

```cs
ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollMode(YourGridView, ScrollMode.Disabled);
```