# Grid View - how to stop moving content

Tags: windows-8

I have written menu like following and it'
s working fine except one thing. When I drag contents of GridView, it's moving slightly what looks bad in that case. Is there any property or way how to stop it. It's menu so I like content not to move when dragged.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054273/metro-app-how-to-disable-gridview-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the `ScrollViewer` on the control, like this...

```
<GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
    <!--Your Content-->
</GridView>
```