# How to stop scrolling while holding?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to disable scrolling when the user start to dispatch holding event. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21850503/1606920) that disables scrolling dinamically, but this only works after I stop holding, what I think is that, because screen's manipulation already started, scroll can't be disabled until user stops to touch the screen.

There is a way to prevent this behavior and stop scrolling while user is holding?

Comment: Use UIElement.ManipulationStarted Event

Comment: @NullPointer, how can I detect holding from `ManipulationStarted`?

Comment: try UIElement.Holding event

Comment: @NullPointer, using `Holding` event is exactly what I'm doing and this generates the problem describred above...